# alternative way for chef to work with sqlplus?

Tags: bash, chef-infra, sqlplus, recipe

could you please tell me if there is a better way how to interact with sqlplus?

```
bash 'create user' do
  user node[:oracle][:user]
  code <<-EOH
    #{node[:sqlplus][:path]}/sqlplus system/#{node[:sqlplus][:SystemPassword]} <<-SQLEOH
    create user #{node[:sqlplus][:user]} identified by #{node[:sqlplus][:user]}
    default tablespace #{node[:sqlplus][:UserTablespace]};
    exit;
    SQLEOH
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bash 'Open SQL Connection for Create user' do
  code <<-EOH
    sqlplus #{dbauser}/#{dbapass}@#{inst_name} as sysdba < C:\\createuser.sql
  EOH
end
```